# How to insert date in MySQL using Java

Tags: java

I have a variable of type Date. I get this date by using a function that return type `Date`. So, I defined two variables as:

```
Date expDate=null, startDate=null;
```

Then, I called the functions:

```
expDate=c.getNotAfter();
startDate= c.getNotBefore();
```

Then, inserted into the database using:

```
prepStmt.setDate(1,(java.sql.Date) startDate);
prepStmt.setDate(2, (java.sql.Date) expDate);
```

After running the program, I get this error:

```
java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.sql.Date
```

The columns in the database are defined as DATETIME type. How can I resolve the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do like this:

```
  prepStmt.setDate(1,new java.sql.Date(startDate.getTime()));
```

`java.sql.Date` is a thin wrapper around a millisecond value that allows [JDBC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity) to identify this as an `SQL DATE` value. A milliseconds value represents the number of milliseconds that have passed since `January 1, 1970 00:00:00.000 GMT`.

java.util.Date classes `getTime()` returns the time in miliseconds. You can use this to create a new object of `java.sql.Date` class.

If you want time along with date, then use Timestamp:

```
prepStmt.setTimestamp(1,new java.sql.Timestamp(startDate.getTime()));
```

Comment: The problem here is that the date s inserted correctly, but the time inserted in the DB as: 00:00:00.

Comment: the you have to use `setTimestamp()` as java.sql.Date discards the time part

Comment: the values that is being stored in the database is in format `10-May-16 12:00:00 AM`, I want it to be stored in the format `10-May-16` what can be done.?

Answer (score 3):

Use it like this:

```
prepStmt.setDate(1,new java.sql.Date(startDate.getTime()));
```

This is because `setDate()` method of `PreparedStatement` requires an object of `java.sql.Date` type as second argument and not `java.util.Date`.

So first get the time in milliseconds from your `java.util.Date` object and then use that in the constructor of `java.sql.Date`.

Answer (score 1):

```
prepStmt.setDate(1, (java.sql.Date) startDate);   
prepStmt.setDate(2, (java.sql.Date) expDate);  
prepStmt.setDate(1, new java.sql.Date(startDate.getTime()));
```